# The responseMessages is not displaying in Django-Swagger integration

Tags: python, django, swagger, django-rest-swagger

I am using DRF YASG to document my API.

I want to remove calls for PUT and PATCH from here. For the views here I have used viewsets.ModelViewSet.

[image: API calls available]

Another app uses APIview for its views.py. How can I exclude methods for a particular url.

My view contains two methods POST and DELETE. But for implementing the methods I have seperate URLs.

The problem is that both the URLs show both methods and the list just gets too big.

[image]

**The question might be similar but I have a constraint of not making  changes in the previous code-base.**